# Script a new web application in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, scripting

I have a script using [AppCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524586.aspx) to create a new application (virtual directory) in IIS 6. To get the script to work in IIS 7 I have to enable IIS 6 compatibility. What is the "right" way to script this in IIS 7 without having to enable a lot of different components that differ from the standard installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [AppCmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/) is what I'm looking for ...